# When submitting one form with ajax then tab index not work on second form

Tags: html, ajax, tabs

Hello on my page there are two form are there in li tag  . when first form submit using ajax then li tag  for second form show (means second form visible) but on second form tab index not working

Comment: It is happening because page is getting refreshed try to use event.preventdefault()

Comment: event.preventdefault() is already use though problem is occurs.is there issue of form submit with post by serialize

Comment: Can you send the code?

Answer (score 0):

add tab index with help of following

$(":input:not(:hidden)").each(function (i) {
  $(this).attr('tabindex', i + 1);

});